# How to extract list from list of list in chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of list something like this
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,3,2],[3,4,6],[7,8,1],[1,4,6]]
size of the list is variable.
now i have to extract two item at one go from list e.g([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
and call a method again take next two element and call it again until all the items gets over.
The Last item can be of size 1.
something like this:

```
def abc(list_of_list_sliced):
 do_something

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,3,2],[3,4,6],[7,8,1],[1,4,6]]
abc([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
abc([7,8,9],[1,3,2])
abc([3,4,6],[7,8,1])
abc([[1,4,6]])
```

Comment: Just loop using `for i in range(0, len(a), 2): abc(a[i : i+2])`

Comment: what about the last element?

Comment: You can iterate over chucks via `list(map(abc, more_itertools.sliced(a, 2)))`.  Install via [`pip install more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sliced).  It will handle leftover items.

Comment: @NishantRanjan It will still work; the slice will simple have fewer elements than you ask for if you have gone off the end of the list (this is not the case when extracting a single index, when you will get an error if you do that).

Comment: Got it! Thanks @alani

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
  abc(a[i:i+2])
```